# How to covert javascript array to php array and load it in a div

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**My problem: I'm not sure how to grab my javascript array (var array) and convert it to a php array.The php array also should be able to grab the values somehow.**

*I've searched for a solution on the internet but I can't really get it to work in this example. I'm also new to Ajax and there are probably some things i'm not doing right. Any help and explanation would be really appreciated.*

**Script.php**

*This file should load the php array in result div.*

```
<div class="test" style="width: 200px height: 50px; background-color: #000;">test</div>
<div class="result" style="width: 200px height: 50px; background-color: yellow; color: #FFF;"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var array = new Array("test", "test");

$(".test").click(function () {
alert('pressed');
array.push("test");
alert(array);
dataString = array; 
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php.php",
        data: {data:dataString}, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**php.php**

*Should echo the javascript array as a php array*

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Add `true` as second parameter to `json_decode()` function. If you still not sure about its structure use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is the ajax call part to insert the data into a div:

---

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php.php",
        data: {data:dataString}, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('.element_class').html(data);
        }
    });
```

---

This is the PHP part:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);

    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
    }
?>
```

---

I havn't tested this myself.